# Write JSON into cloud firestore using node js

Tags: node.js, json, google-cloud-firestore

I have been working with a nested JSON file as given below.
I want to write this JSON to a firestore document using node.js.

```
{
"title":"Sample tittle",
"icon":{
    "type":"url/base64",
    "url":"http://www.sample.com/icon.png"
},
"steps":{
    "step1":{
        "type":"play",
        "url":"http://www.sample.com/"},
    "step2":{
        "type":"ask",
        "url":"http://www.sample.com/ab14",
        "Opts":["yes", "no"],
        "next":[
            {
                "id":"step1",
                "answer":"yes"
            },
            {
                "id":"step3",
                "answer":"no"
            }
        ]
    },
    "step3":{
       "type":"play",
        "url":"http://www.sample.com/ase"}
}
```

}

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far, or a specific issue you are having.

Comment: My main concern is will firestore let me add JSON which contains arrays?

Comment: Isn't your main concern solved once you try it?

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any problem with it. You can find nice reference on GitHub

```
https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/blob/master/README.md
```

I have used it and was able to create document from your JSON like this:

```
const {Firestore} = require('@google-cloud/firestore');

// Create a new client
const firestore = new Firestore();

async function quickstart() {
  // Obtain a document reference.
  const document = firestore.doc('test_collection/test_document');


// Enter new data into the document.
  await document.set({
     <your JSON here>
  });
}
quickstart();
```